Neuroimaging-Genetic studies: is postmortem gene expression equal to invivo gene expression?
I am going to study methods to combine genetic data with neuroimaging data. I have a big perplexity in the methodology. Let us take this research article: Unveiling the Neuroimaging-Genetic Intersections in the Human Brain (Ibai Diez and Jorge Sepulcre).
After figure 1:

Main methods applied to study the spatial association of Image Derived Phenotypes and genetic information. Transcriptome data is
obtained from postmortem brain tissue from different brain regions
across the cortex [...].

Considering that I am not a biologist, how can we assume that postmortem gene expression is equivalent to invivo gene expression ?

We can't, but these studies don't have another source of tissue. Even so, it seems reasonable to assume that differences by group are meaningful.

@BryanKrause do you mean that if I have expression of gene A that is nearly equal among all samples (i.e. post-mortem brains), we can assume that its expression Is that and we can Say that It is higher or lower than gene B expression ?

I mean if there is more expression of gene A in postmortem tissue from Alzheimer's brains than postmortem tissue from other causes of death, that has to represent some difference in those brains and isn't attributable to at least any common postmortem changes. It's rarely meaningful anyways to compare raw expression levels between two different genes.

@BryanKrause however, I think that in Allen brain atlas they did something like mapping the expression of brain genes in order to understand neuronal functions... https://portal.brain-map.org/explore/transcriptome

That would be another example of utilizing differences.
